# how to fetch all times from db which match with posted time?

Tags: mysql, database

This is my front end

[image]

where user choose hospital timing and then again this timing i am trying to fetch doctors from this table only those doctors which have doctor_time_in and doctor_time_out between hospital time which is posted.

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this logic :-

```
doctor_time_in <= STR_TO_DATE('$hospital_time', '%h:%i %p') 
AND doctor_time_out >= STR_TO_DATE('$hospital_time', '%h:%i %p')
```

`STR_TO_DATE` to use for convert your time format in `24` hours

Comment: Thanks it works. please share link of documentation i can't understand %p. :)

Comment: i have 24 hours time it is working fine before 12. let me know what i can do please?

Comment: Thanks now working fine i used this '%H:%i %p' instead of this '%h:%i %p'

Answer (score 1):

Try this query

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE 
doctor_time_in <= DATE_FORMAT('.$posted_time.',"%T") AND 
doctor_time_out >= DATE_FORMAT('.$posted_time.',"%T")
```

The `%T` format will format your posted time to `(hh:mm:ss)` to match the datetime format in your table

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
select hospital_time from table_name where hospital_time between (doctor_time_in,doctor_time_out) and doctor_id = doctor_id_passed;
```